# SPI poll read/write on an MSP430?

Tags: c, embedded, spi, msp430

Sorry for such a simple question, but does anyone have a C example of initializing the MSP430 for SPI mode and performing poll read and write operations? Very new stuff to me and am not sure where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: I would start by bit banging then try the built in spi hardware if there is spi hardware in the particular chip.  You should specify which specific msp430 chip you are using.  Also what peripheral are you going to talk to, that is also important.

Comment: Thanks, should have specified but the MSP430 chip I am using is the MSP430G2553 and my understanding is that it should have built in SPI hardware. Is there a sort of generic method to read/write, leaving out anything specific regarding the peripheral I'm communicating with? I don't have that information at the moment unfortunately, just trying to get a head start.

Comment: Have you tried looking at TI's website?  They have tons of sample code that illustrates just about everything you can do with an MSP430.

Comment: Just wanted to recommend a logic analyzer for debugging SPI - very easy to use, and the 8-channel is $150! http://www.saleae.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look at [MSP430Ware](http://www.ti.com/tool/msp430ware?DCMP=msp430ware&HQS=msp430ware-bhp) which is "a collection of code examples, datasheets and other design resources for ALL MSP430 devices..."